# how to compare elements of two lists in clojure

Tags: list, clojure

I want to compare two list in clojure,

```
(def a '(1 2 3 4 5))
(def b '(3 2 7 8 10))
```

make a result (2 3) or (3 2)
by comparing elements of two lists.

```
(defn compareList[x, y]
  (do
   (def result '())
   (def i 0)
   (def j 0)
   (while (< i 5) 
     (while (< j 5)
       (if (= (nth x i) (nth y j)) 
         (def result (conj (nth x i) result)))
       (def j (inc j))
     )
   )
   result))


(print (compareList a b))
```

it is my code.
but result is (). where i mistake? help please.

Comment: you want the elements, that are in both lists?

Comment: yes!!!! make a new list there are in both lists

Comment: why don't you just intersect two sets?

Comment: Remember that a set is one kind of sequence, which is usually all you want of a list. You can also use `cons` on a set: `(cons 3 #{1 2})` evaluates to `(3 1 2)`.

Answer (score 7):

Using a set would be more appropriate for your case

```
(clojure.set/intersection #{1 2 3 4 5} #{3 2 7 8 10})
```

That will output `#{2 3}`

Comment: how can I do it lazily? e.g. my input is `(def a '(1 2 3 4 5)) (def b (range))` ?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a list comprehension (using the `for` macro, which returns a LazySeq):

```
(for [a '(1 2 3 4 5) b '(3 2 7 8 10)
  :when
  (= a b)]
  a)

;; => (2 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @turingcomplete answer. A set contains only the distinct elements.

You can see that with this:

```
user=> (set '(1 1 2 3 2 4 5 5))
#{1 2 3 4 5}
```

So I think you should accept his answer as correct.